# Loop to convert factors to numeric

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I have in my dataset some factor variables and i try to convert them to numeric with loop

```
a = sample(c('a', 'b'), 100, replace = TRUE)
b = sample(c('a', 'b'), 100, replace = TRUE)
df = as.data.frame(cbind(a, b))
library(plyr); library(dplyr)
for(i in df[, 1:2]) {

  k = as.numeric(as.character(revalue(df[,i],
                                           c('a' = 1,
                                             'b'= 2
                                           ))))
}
```

And i get error

```
Error in revalue(df[, i], c(a = "1", b = "2")) : 
  x is not a factor or a character vector.
```

What's wrong?
NB It is important that 'a' is equal to 1 & 'b' = 2

Comment: You want to do `for(i in 1:2)` (or alternatively `for(i in seq_along(df[, 1:2]))` rather than `for(i in df[, 1:2])`

Comment: For your example data, simply `df$a <- as.numeric(df$a)` and `df$b <- as.numeric(df$b)` will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, R has functionality built in to do this sort of mapping no problems:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) c(a=1,b=2)[as.character(x)] )
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop for that e.g.:

```
library(plyr)
as.data.frame(sapply(df, mapvalues,from = c("a", "b"),to = c(1, 2)))
```

And:

```
df2$a <- as.numeric(as.character(df2$a))
df2$b <- as.numeric(as.character(df2$b))
class(df2$a)
[1] "numeric"
```

Comment: it's a good solution but we get again factor variables. In the real dataset i have 40 variables)))

Answer (score 1):

Just to point this out: a dataframe is a list, and `lapply` is often a good solution to do stuff to lists. ;) For instance, you could try:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x){
  if(is.factor(x)) return(revalue(x, c('a' = 1, 'b'= 2))) 
  else return(x)
}  )
```

This code does the following: for each column, it checks if the column is a factor. If it is a factor, it recodes according to your condition. If it it not a factor, it will leave the data unchanged. You can also change the function that is supplied to `lapply` to do more "elaborate" things.

Answer (score 1):

First we write function

```
 form =function(x)  as.numeric(revalue(x, c('a'= 1, 'b'=2)))
 df[, c(1,2)] = as.data.frame(Map(form, df[, c(1,2)]))
```